# Deploy Service fabric application from powershell without service fabric SDK

Tags: powershell, web-deployment, azure-service-fabric

I am trying to deploy service fabric application from powershell. I am able to deploy with service fabric SDK. is it possible to deploy service fabric application from powershell using powershell scripts without having service fabric sdk installed?(Scenario: in a standalone service fabric cluster)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with standalone clusters, but based on my experience just working with a local dev cluster, **yes, you need the SDK** because it installs both the runtime (without a runtime, what cluster will the scripts connect to?) and the Service Fabric PowerShell module you'll be using (per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/ServiceFabric/?view=azureservicefabricps) for the cmdlets).